# Cannot access 'setContent': it is internal in 'androidx.compose.ui.platform'

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using

- Android Studio 4.3 (Artix Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 5),
- compose_version = '1.0.0-beta01'
- Kotlin version 1.4.30

When I open Empty Compose Activity and compile, I got the below error

```
e: MainActivity.kt: (9, 37): Cannot access 'setContent': it is internal in 'androidx.compose.ui.platform'
```

It's so strange as it is a template-generated project, and should work.
Any workaround it?

Comment: If you update to Arctic Fox Canary 8, do you still have that problem?

Comment: Agree, after changing to `Android Studio 4.3 (Artix Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 8)` all works.
It is now `import androidx.activity.compose.setContent` instead of from `androidx.compose.ui.platform.setContent`

Answer (score 9):

Add this line  in your gradle

```
// In charge of setContent
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.0.0-beta01"
```

`activity-compose` holds the reference for the `setContent` method you need

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.0.0-beta01

> ComponentActivity.setContent() was removed from compose:ui. Use the one from androidx.activity:activity-compose. viewModel() and LocalViewModelStoreOwner were removed from compose:ui. Use the ones from androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose.

Have you added `androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha03` to your dependencies? If you haven't, you should do. If you have, re-import the correct `androidx.activity.compose.setContent`.

By the way, Jetpack Compose is changing fast during its alpha stage so it is not strange that templates of old Android Studio versions are out of date. You'd better keep using the latest Android Studio version if you want to use Jetpack Compose.

Comment: Agree, after changing to `Android Studio 4.3 (Artix Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 8)` all works.
It is now `import androidx.activity.compose.setContent` instead of from `androidx.compose.ui.platform.setContent`

Answer (score 1):

Agree, after changing to `Android Studio 4.3 (Artix Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 8)` all works.
It is now `import androidx.activity.compose.setContent` instead of from `androidx.compose.ui.platform.setContent`. All works now.

Answer (score 1):

Now setContent is part of activity compose not UI.
Add below dependency :
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha03"

It resides inside below package.
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent

I face same issue and this solved the issue.
Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the alpha version to be able to import it:

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0-alpha07'
```

Import:

```kotlin
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
```

Using the non 1.8.0 alpha version it was not found with that import